# Using the YouTube API and extend of fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api

I want to use the new YouTube API in my project.
Using the example of the documentation, it works correctly:

```
public class Test extends  YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    String urlVideo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        urlVideo="5lbVNYAeFiQ";

        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize("MY_API_KEY", this);

    }

    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }

    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1,boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            arg1.loadVideo(urlVideo);
        }

    }
}
```

Well, the problem is when I need the youtube video is displayed within an activity that extends from a fragment

```
public class fragUno extends Fragment { 
...
```

I can not use an activity that extends from a fragment while also use:

```
extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener { ...
```

Has anyone had the same problem?

I searched for information, I find similar issues but not a solution

I sincerely appreciate the help

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically an activity will include, not extend, fragments. For an example how this is done see:  http://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/android-player/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo/FragmentDemoActivity.java. Note that in the example "extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity" is only needed because of common error handling, you don't need to extend the YouTubeBaseActivity to use YouTubePlayerFragment(s).